# How to check whether a number can be represented in the form A^B?

Tags: java

I was recently asked in an interview to write a program to check whether a number can be represented in the form of A^B. I couldn't solve the problem as I weren't even having a correct approach to solve the problem.

Here are a few examples

```
Input = 4
Output = true
```

As it can be represented as 2^2

```
 Input = 536870912
 Output = true
```

As it can be represented as 2^29

```
Input = 1024000000
Output = true
```

As it can be represented as 2^16*5^6 = 32000^2

Can anyone please provide a solution (preferably using Java) to this problem?

Comment: Hint - prime factors. Every integral number can be represented by the product of its prime factors, working out a number's prime factors is called [prime decomposition](http://revisionworld.com/gcse-revision/maths/number-and-algebra/number/numbers/prime-factor-decomposition).

Comment: You can make in the first the square root of the number, then begin dividing the number by all prime numbers which are inferior of its square root, if you find a number you stop, else you continue until you reach 1.

Comment: If there's no restriction on `B`, then just say `true` for everything.  `A = A^1` for all `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an answer for X = A<sup>B</sup> for a known X, with both A ≥ 2 and B ≥ 2 and both being *integers*, then the shortest search is doing A = <sup>B</sup>√X for B = 2..n, until A < 2.

```
public static void findPower(double value) {
    if (value < 1 || value % 1 != 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input: " + value);
    boolean found = false;
    for (int exp = 2; ; exp++) {
        long base = Math.round(Math.pow(value, 1.0 / exp));
        if (base < 2)
            break;
        if (Math.pow(base, exp) == value) {
            System.out.printf("%.0f = %d ^ %d%n", value, base, exp);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (! found)
        System.out.printf("%.0f has no solution%n", value);
}
```

**TEST**

```
findPower(4);
findPower(123_456);
findPower(536_870_912);
findPower(1_024_000_000);
findPower(2_176_782_336d);
findPower(205_891_132_094_649d);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4 = 2 ^ 2
123456 has no solution
536870912 = 2 ^ 29
1024000000 = 32000 ^ 2
2176782336 = 46656 ^ 2
2176782336 = 1296 ^ 3
2176782336 = 216 ^ 4
2176782336 = 36 ^ 6
2176782336 = 6 ^ 12
205891132094649 = 14348907 ^ 2
205891132094649 = 59049 ^ 3
205891132094649 = 729 ^ 5
205891132094649 = 243 ^ 6
205891132094649 = 27 ^ 10
205891132094649 = 9 ^ 15
205891132094649 = 3 ^ 30
```